# More than one pager in the same page

Tags: 7, paging

I have a Page that contains two views one that list the latest news and the other list the latest event

The problem now is that each view has a pager but when I change the page of one of them both view will change.
i.e If I want to see page number 3 in news view,the event view will also change to page number 3

Is there is a way to make that even programmatically
also I don't want to make it ajax because I need to share the url

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Pager options* There is a field named *Pager ID*. Setting a different value for each view should solve the problem.

Comment: Do you know how to set Pager ID to a different value it make a lot of error when change the default value

Comment: What errors?...

Comment: I change the 0 value to be 1 "Notice: Undefined index: 1 in theme_pager() (line 331 of /includes\pager.inc)."

Comment: I have replaced value '0' with '1'(any value). This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Make View Results Ajaxified.. Enable the AJAX Feature in the view settings. You can do this by editing the view and make the **Use AJAX** setting under **Other** settings in the view to YES.

With out using AJAX you can solve this using the **Pager ID** setting in the pager settings. For first view leave the Pager ID to default 0. For the second view in the same page, edit the view and set the pager ID to 1. Make sure all the views in a single page have different pager ID's.

Comment: is there is any other solutions for that I don't know to make it ajax :) because I need to change url to share the link

Comment: @Ahmed You should simply enable Ajax under the view setting, and it is Ajax. You don't have to know any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very tutorial on [nodeone.se](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/670) about what you want to achieve.

But it's almost the same answer than H.NiK...Only difference,he only changed the id pager of one view (the block not the page)

Maybe this video will be helpful.